# Sending News letters using mailchimp

Tags: php, mailchimp

I have newsletter section of my site. I am new to Mailchimp api.
I have seen mailchimp api document but I dont get ideas how to fulfill my requirement.

In my site, the users can create their own **Groups**
The other users can join particular group with under 2 categories:

1. Just joined
2. Wishlist

Any number of ***users*** can join to particular Group. At the same time, any number of ***Groups*** can be created by the users from my site.

For Example:

Lets assume, we have Group (named 'Taj mahal'). In that group, 10 users are '*Just joined*' category and 5 users are '*Wishlist*'.

I want to send newsletters by every week, by category wise (whether Just joined / wishlist ) with different mail contents(week by week).

Anyone help me...

Answer (score 0):

First you need to include mailchimp api to your php libraries.As your requirement you need to listout all group names . For that you can use listInterestGroups() function. Then you can add customers to groups with MailchimpListBatchSubscribe() function. I hope that it will be helpful for you.